# execute 2 commands within container

Tags: docker

When I run this, the first command works but the command after "&&" is executed on host instead of within container.

```
docker run -p 7778:7778 -t continuumio/miniconda conda  install -c conda-forge -y jupyter && ipython notebook --ip=* --port=7778
```

Is there any way to run both the commands within container?
I am looking for a way to to do this at command prompt without using script file.

Comment: It's sometimes cleaner to mount a bash script as a volume and have your docker command run that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke multiple commands via Bash:

```
docker run -p 7778:7778 -t continuumio/miniconda /bin/bash -c 'conda  install -c conda-forge -y jupyter && ipython notebook --ip=* --port=7778'
```